# ctrl key not working [windows 10 laptop]

Tags: windows, keyboard

I have a windows 10 laptop. Both control keys stopped working suddenly. How can I check if it is an OS issue or hardware issue? Did virus scan its clean. I tried disabling sticky keys from control panel but none of it worked. Is there a control lock?

Comment: This could be a hardware issue.

Comment: You can create a _bootable usb_ and run some hardware check. Search on google `bootable usb system diagnostics` or e.g. try [something like this](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) (it was on the 1st page).

Comment: yes but how to confirm that?

Comment: @hastur ok will try that. btw external keyboard is working just fine

Comment: @Shreyans - If an external keyboard is working then you have a hardware problem.  If only one key isn't working that would make sense.  You will need to start using the external keyboard instead of the built-in keyboard.

Comment: Sometimes the ctrl/shift/alt key combinations get struck in a strange state so that the OS thinks that one is permanently down. Try pressing each of them seperately a few times (this normally fixes it). Also have you tried restarting?

Comment: Do not forget to come back to say what happens... :-)  Note that nowadays [it is possible to distinguish between RIGHT and LEFT Ctrl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27394057/3569208), check if the diagnostic software is able to do it. (It can turn useful  in case you jammed a button contact below the keyboard, or there is something to remove or unlock over there as dust, crumbs, dead bugs body... :D ).

Comment: ok so most likely it was an hardware issue coz i had broken a lock on my motherboard where the wire from the keyboard went. But it was repaired and almost everything was woking fine (except for the ctrl key and the touchpad backlight which was a different color fo some strange reason). I do not know what fixed it but now my ctrl key is working just fine. Thanks for all your help guys. Ill be sure to update if i find anything new about my situation.